# Laravel: Function name must be a string

Tags: laravel

I'm currently working on a project. It was all working just fine until i tried to migrate some tables that I edited. I got this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>     Function name must be a string

Since I doesn't directly show me where the error is, I couldn't find it. Last things I changed before I tried to migrate tables:

- Migrations
- Laravel colletive/html forms
- Store method in my controller

As I know, migrations and forms shouldn't be a problem with this error, so here's my controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $input = $request->all();

    if ($file = $request->file('photo_id')){
        $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
    }

    $user->posts()->create($input);
    return redirect('/userPanel');
}
```

If the error isn't even in a controller code, where could it be. Any help appreciated.

Comment: check the [stacktrace] in storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Got the exact path where the problem was.

Comment: @zlatangoralija Feel free to post the solution so others may benefit and learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found out it was because of a very silly mistake, i was calling a variable as a function...

```
$ownedMacs = intval($data()['owned_mac']);
```

Changed to

```
$ownedMacs = intval($data['owned_mac']);
```

This error message usually appears when we are doing something real stupid! :)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue in Laravel can solve

```
    Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
    Function name must be a string
```

When you checked on `storage/logs/laravel.log`

```
local.ERROR: Function name must be a string {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Function name must be a string at E:\\Project\\workspace\\turttyKidsProject\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\SiteContactController.php:52)
```

[stacktrace]

Solution 
Data field requesting another format but you are trying to save an object.

```
            $objectSave= new ObjectClass;
            $objectSave->feild_db = $request->post('request_name');
```

Check whether you access request with your form submit method. it may be `POST or GET`